# chrome extension Content Security Policy1

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I have this error in implementing chrome extension.
Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/js/api.js 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome Extension manifest v3 [remotely hosted code is no longer allowed](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code). And inline scripts.

Pls see [How can I use the Google API in a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55935126/how-can-i-use-the-google-api-in-a-chrome-extension) for workarounds.